# The smallest prime factor with a set of digits

Tags: arithmetic, prime-factorization

I was wondering if there was a way to logically/mathematically derive what the smallest possible largest prime factor to a number was, using each of the digits 1-9 only once.

An example could be 123456789, which has a largest prime factor of 3803.

I tried 164385792 by experimenting with the exponent of 2, but that came out with 17837.

Is there a way to find the minimum largest prime factor without using brute force?

Comment: Since when is $3808$ prime?

Comment: It's unlikely you'll find a solution that isn't just brute force, or close to brute force.

Comment: @barak: The OP meant $3803$.

Comment: @barakmanos sorry, should've typed in 3803

Comment: @awesomepi What is meant with "minimum largest prime factor" ?